# error LNK2001 when compiling in Release mode in VS2012

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, linker

My windows phone 8 application compiles fine in Debug mode, but when I switch to Release mode, I encounter a few link errors. The unresolved external symbols are for functions I have defined myself, not from external libraries. 
I have a .h file for the function declaration, and a .c for its implementation. The module calling these functions is also a .c file. Both source files are explicitly compiled as C code (I have c++ code in my project too). VS2012 can locate the function definitions when I right click on the function call and click "Go To Definition". I've made sure that none of the declarations/definitions are wrapped in #ifdef NDEBUG. What could be causing this linkage problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the settings between debug and release mode in your project properties. You may excluded some of your implementation files from build. If you have multiple projects in the solution then you may forget to set the correct dependency between them in release mode.

Comment: Looks like the person who I inherited this project from changed the default object file name for the project. Thanks for the tip!